# difference b/w [ab] and (a|b) in regex match?

Tags: python, regex

I knew that `[]` denotes a set of allowable characters -

```
>>> p = r'^[ab]$'
>>> 
>>> re.search(p, '')
>>> re.search(p, 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004823d8>
>>> re.search(p, 'b')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100482370>
>>> re.search(p, 'ab')
>>> re.search(p, 'ba')
```

But ... today I came across an expression with vertical bars within parenthesis to define mutually exclusive patterns -

```
>>> q = r'^(a|b)$'
>>> 
>>> re.search(q, '')
>>> re.search(q, 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100498dc8>
>>> re.search(q, 'b')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100498e40>
>>> re.search(q, 'ab')
>>> re.search(q, 'ba')
```

This seems to mimic the same functionality as above, or am I missing something?

PS: In `Python` parenthesis themselves are used to define logical groups of matched text. If I use the second technique, then how do I use parenthesis for both jobs?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean with the parenthesis bit...

Comment: Yes, you are correct - `[ab]` and `(a|b)` both match _exactly_ the same thing (but the first one will match faster). Regular expressions are a language unto themselves (whether you find them in Python or Perl) and you need to learn their (cryptic) syntax if you plan to use them effectively. (e.g. Parentheses inside a regex are not the same as parentheses outside the regex.) I recommend following the tutorial at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info). Any time spent there will be rewarded many times over.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In this case it is the same.

However, the alternation is not just limited to a single character. For instance,

```
^(hello|world)$
```

will match "hello" or "world" (and *only* these two inputs) while

```
^[helloworld]$
```

would just match a single character ("h" or "w" or "d" or whatnot).

Happy coding.

Answer (score 19):

`[ab]` matches one character (a or b) and doesn't capture the group. `(a|b)` captures a or b, and matches it. In this case, no big difference, but in more complex cases `[]` can only contain characters and character classes, while `(|)` can contain arbitrarily complex regex's on either side of the pipe

Answer (score 4):

In the example you gave they are interchangeable.  There are some differences worth noting:

In the character class square brackets you don't have to escape anything but a dash or square brackets, or the caret ^ (but then only if it's the first character.)

Parentheses capture matches so you can refer to them later.  Character class matches don't do that.

You can match multi-character strings in parentheses but not in character classes